# TableView - “Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range in Swift”

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm pulling data from the database, I'm having no problems with data, but I'm having trouble transferring this data to the text in the Cell. I think I'm having a problem with the `numberOfRowsInSection` count. I want to add as much data as the sum of the two data, but I'm having trouble this way.

```swift
class ChatRoomViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var bilgiCevap = [String]()
    var bilgiKullanıcı = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        FCevap()
        chatTableView.delegate = self
        chatTableView.dataSource = self
        func FCevap(){
            let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!

            client.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") { success in
                client.execute("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE . LIKE '\(self.form_no)' AND ... LIKE '0'", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                    for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                        for row in table {
                            for (_, value) in row {
                                if let intVal = value as? String {
                                    self.bilgiKullanıcı.append(String(intVal))
                                }} }}
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.Kullanici()
                        self.chatTableView.reloadData()}

                    client.disconnect() }) }
        }

        func Kullanıcı(){
            let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!

            client.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") { success in
                client.execute("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIKE '\(self.form_no)' AND ... LIKE '1'", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                    for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                        for row in table {
                            for (_, value) in row {
                                if let intVal = value as? String {
                                    self.bilgiCevap.append(String(intVal))
                                }} }}
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {self.chatTableView.reloadData()}
                    client.disconnect() }) }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatCell") as! ChatCell

            let messageGıden = self.bilgiKullanıcı[indexPath.row]
            cell.chatTextView.text = messageGıden
            cell.usernameLabel.text = "..."
            cell.setBubbleType(type: .incoming)

            let messageGelen = self.bilgiCevap[indexPath.row]
            cell.chatTextView2.text = messageGelen
            cell.userNameLabel2.text = "Kullanıcı"
            cell.setBubbleType2(type: .outgoing)
            return cell
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return bilgiCevap.count + bilgiKullanici.count
        }
}
```

Comment: in order to avoid this crash you should have same number of objects in your arrays, or create a new one with the information you need and use only one array to feed the table (I recommend last option)

Comment: Can I add and use two sequences in the same series? But I have to use two separate strings because they are different values. How will I do? @emelagumat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have data sources you need to take two Sections in number of section delegate.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

And in numberOfRows section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return dataSource1.count
    } else {
        return dataSource2.count
    }
}
```

and then inside cellFor rowAt delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let data = dataSource1[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        let data = dataSource2[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```